# Braiding 3 Phase Wires

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, low-voltage, emi-filtering

I'm working in the 50V, 10A range with un-shielded wire to drive a brushless DC motor. Are there any advantages to braiding the 3 phase wires? will it reduce EMI and spiking?

Comment: The EMI radiation level is proportional to the area of the loop in each phase wire to wire, so yes twisted wires reduce external radiation, reducing spike from inductive switching, no

Comment: It will look nice. And keep the wires together in one bundle. You could also get a 3-conductor cable where all three wires are inside of one outer jacket.

Answer (score 1):

Twisting reduces electromagnetic effects (both radiation and reception) in two ways. Firstly if the wires are loose twisting them keeps them close together. Secondly twisting mixes up the direction of the magnetic fields so when viewed from a distance they mostly cancel.

I would expect braiding to have a similar impact electrically to twisting with the advantage that it won't come un-twisted.